# ISO 8601 datetime now

Tags: java, c#, date, datetime

I need exactly that format in java which in C# is
`DateTime.Now.ToString("o")`. Sample returned date for `DateTime.Now.ToString("o")` is

> 2016-03-10T11:24:59.7862749+04:00

and then in **sql it's inserted as**

> 2016-03-10 11:24:59.786

I'm trying to insert same date format from java. I use that:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ");
df.setTimeZone(tz);
String nowAsISO = df.format(new Date());
```

and it returns this

> 2016-03-10T07:29+0000

Because of that format then it goes in error. How can I change format to be exactly which I want?

Comment: Why do you insert your DateTime as a string? Just insert it as such and format it when you need to represent it? If you use Sql Server, `datetime` and `datetime2` types does not keep offset part. You might wanna use `datetimeoffset` type instead. And you didn't _even_ show how you insert this value to your database and how you get from it.

Comment: @SonerGönül this format is in web service. I can't change it.. I'm only calling it and need to pass. without it service goes in 500 error

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis because i want that format in java. that code which I've mentioned is in java!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For Java 7 you can use:**

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
```

This uses the pattern symbol XXX which will print the colon inside the offset, too. However, for Java-6 this feature is not offered. And the precision is always constrained to milliseconds.

**For Java-8, you can also use:**

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.now().format(dtf)); // 2016-03-10T08:46:44.849+01:00
```

This enables nanosecond precision if such a clock is available (starting with Java-9).

**For Java-6** either apply a hack based on `SimpleDateFormat` or use external libraries:

```
// Java-6 (SimpleDateFormat)
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
String text = sdf.format(new Date());
text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 2) + ":" + text.substring(text.length() - 2);
System.out.println(text);

// Joda-Time
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ").print(now));

// Time4J
Moment now = SystemClock.currentMoment();
System.out.println(Iso8601Format.EXTENDED_DATE_TIME_OFFSET.withStdTimezone().format(now));
```

Comment: @George I am not sure why you want to omit the offset ("without XXX"). In this case, you are just sending a plain timestamp without offset information indicating your local time. But even if the webservice accepts this format it is potentially harmful because the webservice could misinterprete it when translating to UTC in database layer.

Answer (score 4):

The [Answer by Meno Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35910515/642706) is correct. I'll just add some more comments and some SQL-specific code.

## Avoid Old Date-Time Classes

The old date-time classes, java.util.Date/.Calendar & java.text.SimpleDateFormat, are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them.

The old clases have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

For use before Java 8, check out the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

## Nanoseconds

The java.time classes have nanosecond resolution. So you will not have the problem of data loss where `2016-03-10T11:24:59.7862749+04:00` gets truncated to `2016-03-10 11:24:59.786` because of millisecond resolution used by the old classes.

Getting the current moment in Java 8 is limited to milliseconds, three digits of decimal fraction of second, due to legacy issue. Java 9 will get the current moment in nanoseconds, up to nine digits of decimal fraction (provided your computer’s hardware clock can provide such fine resolution).

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines sensible text formats for date-time values. For example, `2016-03-09T23:24:33Z` or `2016-03-09T22:24:33-01:00`. The java.time classes use these by default, so no need to define parsing patterns.

## Instant

An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Call `Instant::toString` to generate a string in standard format.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2016-03-09T23:24:33.123Z

## `OffsetDateTime`

Apply a `ZoneOffset` to get an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes( -5 , 30 );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneOffset );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you know the full time zone rather than just the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ); // "Europe/Paris", "America/Montreal", etc.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

## `java.sql.Timestamp`

Hopefully the JDBC drivers will be updated to directly use the java.time types. Until then we convert to java.sql types for transferring data in/out of database.

As noted above, java.time can handle nanoseconds. So does `java.sql.Timestamp`. But your database may not. Some databases are limited to whole seconds, milliseconds, or microseconds. When data is passed via JDBC to the database, the database may truncate.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
```

…and going the other direction…

```
Instant instant = ts.toInstant();
```

Note that an `Instant` is always in UTC by definition. So no need to perform the kind of code attempted at the end of the Question.

## Work Flow

You should minimize your use of strings when working with date-time. Maximize your use of helpful date-time classes/objects, namely java.time classes. Stop thinking of strings as date-time values -- they are a *textual representation* of a date-time value.

**Do not insert/retrieve date-time values to/from your database as strings.** Use the java.sql objects such as `java.sql.Timestamp` and `java.sql.Date`. Use `PreparedStatement` and the "set/get" methods such as `setTimestamp`/`getTimestamp`. And virtually [always define your columns](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/use-timestamptz.html) in database as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` rather than “without time zone”.

When getting data from database, use the java.sql types. But as soon as is possible, convert to java.time types. The java.sql types are a mess, a dirty hack, and should be used only for data transfer not business logic.

Generally best to use [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) in your business logic, data storage, data exchange, API calls, and so on. Adjust into a time zone only when expected by a user or required by a data sink.

Answer (score 2):

use this format **"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"**

## Example:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: thanks but now that returned `2016-03-10T07:40:09.0619+0000` and it anyway went in error..

Comment: http 500. it's about date format. When i'll hardcode it in format which i've mentioned in question it works well

Comment: Attention: Four times using "S" for the fraction of second is definitely wrong.